# Can't call methods in class

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm currently working on some school project; we are developing a simple RPG, but I seem to be questioning some of my Java code.

I have an `Abstract` class called `Item`, then I have `Armor` and `Weapon` classes which both inherit from `Item`. Both `Armor` and `Weapon` have some attributes that `Item` doesn't have.

So in my database wrapper, I have a `loaditem` method, which gets the stats and creates an instance of my class (read comments in code):

```
public Item loadItem(int itemID)
{
    // Setting item, as a Item, as it can be both Weapon or Armor 
    Item item;

    try {

        // Build prepared statement
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM item WHERE iid = ?");

        // Set Parameter
        stmt.setInt(1, itemID);

        // Execute the query
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        // Get row
        rs.first();

        // Set all values and keys


        if(rs.getString("type").equals("weapon")) { 
            item = new Weapon();
            // SetDamage is unique to Weapon, and setDefense to armor  
            item.setDamage();
        }else {
            item = new Armor();
            item.setDefense()
        }

        item.setIid(rs.getInt("iid"));
        item.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        item.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
        item.setSellValue(rs.getInt("sellvalue"));
        item.setBuyValue(rs.getInt("buyvalue"));
        item.setStrength(rs.getInt("strength"));
        item.setAgility(rs.getInt("agility"));
        item.setEndurance(rs.getInt("endurance"));
```

I have no problem setting a instance of `Weapon` or `Armor` to item, but it can't find the methods in the classes.

Do I really need to create both a weapon and an armor object, and return after type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you're going to call an instance method, the "target" expression of the method call must have a *compile-time* type which is known to have the appropriate method. The compiler needs to resolve the method calls *at compile time*. (Any overload resolution is done at compile-time; the actual implementation is decided at execution time based on polymorphism of course.)

It's unclear why you'd want the `item` variable in the first place. It sounds like you should just have:

```
if (rs.getString("type").equals("weapon")) { 
    Weapon weapon = new Weapon();
    weapon.setDamage();
    return weapon;
} else {
    Armor armor = new Armor();
    armor.setDefense();
    return armor;
}
```

That's assuming you want to return immediately - your code was truncated, so it's not clear. If you really *do* need the `item` variable, you can just assign `weapon` or `armor` to `item` where I have the return statements above.

EDIT: It sounds like that's the case, so you'd have:

```
// I'd still declare `item` as late as possible, i.e. here rather than
// outside the `try` block, unless you *also* need it outside the try block...
Item item;
if (rs.getString("type").equals("weapon")) { 
    Weapon weapon = new Weapon();
    weapon.setDamage();
    item = weapon;
} else {
    Armor armor = new Armor();
    armor.setDefense();
    item = armor;
}
// Other code using `item` here
```

In fact, you may well want to put the code to initialize the weapon into a separate method. Then you could use:

```
String type = rs.getString("type");
Item item = type.equals("weapon")) ? createWeapon() : createArmor();
```

Comment: Because if i create an instance inside the if, i can only use it there. The item got loads of stats itself, so if i were to use your example i would have to write 10 setters in both the if and the else. Which just seems stupid.But if there is no way around. :)

Comment: @MartinElvarJensen: Well if you'd actually *shown* other code using `item` after the `if` statement, I'd have written the answer differently. I can't guess at code that you have neither shown nor described!

Comment: Thx a bunch Jon, you have been a great help :). Also thx to everyone else for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
    if (...) {
      Weapon w = new Weapon();
      // SetDamage is unique to Weapon, and setDefense to armor  
      w.setDamage();
      item = w;
    } else {
      ...
    }
```

After that `if` block/sequence, you can use `item` before you return. But you can only call methods of the `Item` class on it. Similarly, the callers of your `loadItem` method can only use the methods from the `Item` class on the value you return, unless they *carefully* use a cast.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a method unique to "Weapon" you must cast the item pointer to Weapon, thus:

```
Weapon weaponPointer = (Weapon)item;
weaponPointer.setDamage();
```

Comment: Given that it's being constructed in the previous line, there's no need to cast here - just use a separate variable.

Comment: True, but it works in the general case, which the others don't.

Answer (score 0):

item = new Weapon() will make item refer to a Weapon instance but item will not become Weapon, in order to refer to Weapon of Armor methods you can do one of the following:

```
if (rs.getString("type").equals("weapon")) { 
   Weapon weapon = new Weapon();
   weapon.setDamage();
   return weapon;
} else {
   Armor armor = new Armor();
   armor.setDefense();
   return armor;
```

}

or

```
if (rs.getString("type").equals("weapon")) { 
item = new Weapon();
((Weapon)item).setDamage();
} else {
item = new Armor();
((Armor)item).setDefense();
}
```

return item

Comment: So are you actually casting it, in your second example?

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish the instance type and reference type;

```
Item myItem = new Weapon();
```

Instance type: Weapon
Reference type: Item

So if you call a method on myItem it can be only method of Item class. Because your reference type is Item.

In your case you want to call a method of Weapon so your reference type has to be Weapon too.

```
Weapon myWeapon = new Weapon();
item.setDamage(); // method of Weapon class, it's ok
```

Pay attention to reference type and instance type!

I think This answer is best: (thanks to Jon Skeet)

```
// I'd still declare `item` as late as possible, i.e. here rather than
// outside the `try` block, unless you *also* need it outside the try block...
Item item;
if (rs.getString("type").equals("weapon")) { 
    Weapon weapon = new Weapon();
    weapon.setDamage();
    item = weapon;
} else {
    Armor armor = new Armor();
    armor.setDefense();
    item = armor;
}
// Other code using `item` here
```